# get userinput from bash script (executed by cron or udev)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, console

EDIT, the question might have not been totally clear, short version:

How to popup a dialog asking for user input if the script is running in the background and not in an active console?
/EDIT

When I run a bash script from udev or cron, it usually runs quietly somewhere in the background. Example could be plugging in an external harddrive runs rsync for data backup. So not every time I plug in the harddrive do I want to launch this action.

What is the most minimal way to fire up some user input dialog and ask yes or no? I could write some interface with PyQt but I want as little dependencies as possible, ideally cross window manager and maybe even without window manager.

Thanks!

Comment: What if the user is not logged in at all?

Comment: let's assume the user is logged in, I plug in the hardrive because I want to interact with it (so I am logged in), now I want to fire up a script asking me yes / now do you want to run the backup rsync

Comment: What if more than one user is logged in? How do you decide who gets the prompt? Generally, requesting user interaction in `cron`/`udev`/... is not a particularly good design... Although, both KDE and Gnome have applet/widget thingies that can pop up a notification on certain hardware events. Perhaps looking into how to customize those is what you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2: The lightweight (and hence as ugly as expected) version is xmessage, this would probably be the answer to the question, unless you have a better one:

```
xmessage  "Do you want to run the backup script?" -buttons yes,no
```

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/87/using-gui-dialog-box/

EDIT: So there's KDialog for kde, is there something really lightweight for X?

http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2009/99/Zenity-and-KDialog

```
kdialog --title "Do you want to run the backup script?"
--yesno "Do you want to run the backup script?"
```

I'm currently leaning towards zenity, only trouble is it pulls in a whole array of gtk dependencies on kde, but is cross platform and works on windows. In essence, this is exaclty what I was looking for:

```
if zenity --question --text="Please press a button."; then
    zenity --info --text="You pressed Yes\!"
else
    zenity --error --text="You pressed No\!"
fi
```

But was hoping it would be a lot lighter on the resources / dependencies. Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be for the automated script to simply email you, or perhaps alert with `wall` with instructions (containing the location of the real script).

Another approach would be for the automated script to `touch` a file in `/var/lib` and proceed if the file is still present after 5 minutes. This gives the user the option to stop the process (by removing the file), but maintains some automation.

Comment: I'm looking more at an immediate popup / userdialog style interaction

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should have cron or udev handling in the first place. Write a userland daemon that listens for the appropriate D-Bus messages and performs the appropriate actions.

Comment: are there good reasons not to use udev? I have udev handle plug in all sorts or peripherals, like external monitor etc, why would shouldn't it be used for external harddrive? I'm sure you have a point, just curious..

Comment: Yes. It doesn't do user interaction.

Comment: True, kinda, that's why the question is asked, one can have udev launch the script with konsole -e /path/rsync_back.sh and use read or dialog to get the userinput (needs to detect the local terminal programs, this is what I wanted to avoid) or use zenity. Writing a daemon is probably even less portable and has even more dependencies

Comment: What you're doing is not portable to begin with. Windows and OS X have completely different hotplug notification mechanisms altogether.

Comment: True, and I'm using neither on top of it, I think I'll probably just stick with kdialog

Comment: Don't forget to pick the correct value for `$DISPLAY` before using it though.

Answer (score 0):

This should be post in linux or superuser or serverfault.

But, the number one google search on **linux read user input** links back here to StackOverflow: 
https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+read+user+input&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb

so I guess it's not too off base.

Again, the third or so google result for **linux invoke command usb device plugin** links to ServerFault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/399698/execute-a-command-when-a-device-is-connected-via-usb

I'll leave combining those two as an exercise.

Comment: I think the question was understood the wrong way, I know how to invoke USB udev rules and to collect user input. The question is how to collect userinput from a script that is running in the background, not in an active console